# Display flex and vertical align middle, without moving content side by side?

Tags: css, flexbox

Let's say I have this aligned item to the center, but I don't want the side by side stacking. I want the About us header to be left justified above the paragraph and not side by side. Is there a way to align this content to the center but, still use flex box as its means of adjusting?

So it should like like...

```
About Us
Paragraph.
```

and not like...

```
About us Paragraph
```

Can flex box do this without moving the content beside one another? I know that's kind of the purpose of flex box.

```css
.list {
  float:left;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 15px;
}

.about {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 250px;
]
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="some/image" alt="">
  <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="some/image" alt="">
</div>
<div class="about">
  <h2 class="mb-4 header-main">About Us text</h2>
  <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) to column:

```css
.list {
  float:left;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 15px;
}

.about {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 250px;
]
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="some/image" alt="">
  <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="some/image" alt="">
</div>
<div class="about">
  <h2 class="mb-4 header-main">About Us text</h2>
  <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```